# How to configure highcharts so that all the curves are always displayed / highlighted?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to configure highcharts in such way that when the mouse goes over the chart all the curves remain displayed / highlighted and the value of the curve closest to the mouse is displayed.

In this jsfidle example provided originally by @Wojciech Chmiel : [ https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rLg0kwp7 ]

```js
var monoChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
   zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      439,
      525,
      571,
      696,
      970,
      119,
      137,
      154
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      234,
      123,
      444,
      322,
      543,
      657
    ]
  }],
});

monoChart._highChartsZoom = monoChart.zoom;
monoChart.zoom = function(e) {
  this._highChartsZoom(e);
}.bind(monoChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

We can see that if the mouse is nearby curve of "Series 1", the closest value is displayed (which is great) but the curve of "Series 2" has been hidden automatically which I would like to avoid in my case.
See the screenshot : [example of interactive chart display with highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaGmr.png)

I would like to have the same display but with all the curves displayed / highlighted even if the user is doing a "mouse over" on the chart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the `inactive` state by setting `opacity` in the state option to `1`.

```js
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
        inactive: {
            opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states.inactive.opacity

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rLg0kwp7/2/

Comment: Great ! This is working just fine.
Thanks a lot.
N.B. : furthermore it's useful to know that opacity is a real with a [0,1] range.